# system.collection.generic.keyNotFoundException

Tags: c#, selenium, generics, specflow

I am getting System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException while trying to open a Browser. Can any one please look into this issue. Please find the below files,

App.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="specFlow" type="TechTalk.SpecFlow.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionHandler, TechTalk.SpecFlow" />
    <section name="autofac" type="Autofac.Configuration.SectionHandler, Autofac.Configuration" />
  </configSections>

<appSettings>
    <add key="seleniumBaseUrl" value="http://www.verivox.de/" />
</appSettings>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="TechTalk.SpecFlow" publicKeyToken="0778194805d6db41" culture="neutral" />
        <assemblyIdentity name="TechTalk.SpecFlow" publicKeyToken="0778194805d6db41" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" newVersion="1.9.0.77" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <autofac>
    <components>
      <component name="IE" type="OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerDriver, WebDriver" service="OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver, WebDriver" instance-scope="per-dependency">
      </component>
      <component name="Chrome" type="OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver, WebDriver" service="OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver, WebDriver" instance-scope="per-dependency">
      </component>
      <component name="Firefox" type="OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver, WebDriver" service="OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver, WebDriver" instance-scope="per-dependency">
      </component>
      <!-- Example of using an injected RemoteDriver:
      <component
              name="IE"
              type="Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit.RemoteWebDriver, Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit.SpecFlowPlugin"
              service="OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver, WebDriver"
              instance-scope="per-dependency">
        <parameters>
          <parameter name="url" value="http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub" />
          <parameter name="browser" value="InternetExplorer">
          </parameter>
        </parameters>
      </component>-->
    </components>
  </autofac></configuration>
```

My Feature File,

```
Feature: CalculatorVerification
    Feature to test all the calculator functionlity
    Here we will test all the calcu

@Browser:IE
@SmokeTest
Scenario: Verify Girokonto Claculator functionality
    Given I have navigate to Girokonto Calculator Page
    And I see the calculator page fully loaded
    When I click on the Jetzt vergleichen! button
    Then Girokonten im Vergleich page should load
```

My Step Definition File,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit.Bindings;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
using Verivox.Pages;

namespace Verivox.Steps
{
    [Binding]
    class StrompreisvergleichSteps
    {

        [Given(@"I am on Verivox Home Page")]
        public void GivenIAmOnVerivoxHomePage()
        {
            Browser.Current.Navigate().GoToUrl(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["seleniumBaseUrl"]);
            PropertyCollection.currentPage = new HomePage();

        }

        [When(@"I have entered (.*) and (.*)")]
        public void WhenIHaveEnteredAnd(String postalCode, String Usage)
        {
            PropertyCollection.currentPage.As<HomePage>().EnterPostalCode(postalCode);
            PropertyCollection.currentPage.As<HomePage>().EnterUsage(Usage);
        }

        [When(@"I clicked on Jetzt verglei button")]
        public void WhenIClickedOnJetztVergleiButton()
        {
            PropertyCollection.currentPage = PropertyCollection.currentPage.As<HomePage>().SubmitStrom();
        }

        [When(@"I clik on Jetzt wechsein button in the eprimo in Strom Page")]
        public void WhenIClikOnJetztWechseinButtonInTheEprimoInStromPage()
        {
            PropertyCollection.currentPage = PropertyCollection.currentPage.As<StromPage>().clickItemJetztButton();
        }

        [Then(@"the eprimo Strom page appear")]
        public void ThenTheEprimoStromPageAppear()
        {
            PropertyCollection.currentPage.As<EprimoPage>().verifyPageHeader();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: which line does the error occur? Have you debugged the issue?

Comment: Hi Sam, It's failing at Browser.Current. You can find it in Step definition file.May be i missed something in App.config file.

Comment: Are you using SpecFlow >= 2? Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit does only work with SpecFlow 1.9.